# How do I select a max date by person in a table

Tags: sql, date, filter, reporting-services, max

I am not too advanced with SSRS/SQL queries, and need to write a report that pulls out % allocations by person to then compare to a wage table to allocate the wages. These allocations change quarterly, but all allocations continue to be stored in the table. If a persons allocation did not change, they do NOT get a new entry in the table. Here is a sample table called Allocations.

| First Name | Last Name | Date | Area | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | Bob | 01/01/20 | A | 50.00 |
| Smith | Bob | 01/01/20 | B | 50.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 01/01/20 | A | 25.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 01/01/20 | B | 25.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 01/01/20 | C | 50.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 04/01/20 | A | 35.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 04/01/20 | C | 65.00 |
| Wayne | Bruce | 01/01/20 | A | 100.00 |
| Wayne | Bruce | 04/01/20 | B | 100.00 |

The results that I would want to have from this sample table when querying it are:

| First Name | Last Name | Date | Area | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | Bob | 01/01/20 | A | 50.00 |
| Smith | Bob | 01/01/20 | B | 50.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 04/01/20 | A | 35.00 |
| Doe | Jane | 04/01/20 | C | 65.00 |
| Wayne | Bruce | 04/01/20 | B | 100.00 |

However, I would also like to pull this by comparing it to a date that the user inputs, so that they could run this report at any point in time and get the correct "max" dates. So, for example, if there were also 7/1/20 dates in here, but the user input date was 6/30/20, I would NOT want to pull the 7/1/20 data. In other words, I would like to pull the rows with the maximum date by name w/o going over the user's input date.

Any idea on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, ROW_NUMBER can be used to order records in groups by a particular field.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Last_Name, First_Name ORDER BY DATE DESC) as ROW_NUM 
FROM TABLE
) AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Then you filter for `ROW_NUM = 1`.

However, I noticed that there are a couple with the same date and you want both. In this caseyou'd want to use RANK - which allows for ties so there may be multiple records with the same date that you want to capture.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY Last_Name, First_Name ORDER BY DATE DESC) as ROW_NUM 
FROM TABLE
) AS T
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this. I had actually tried ROW previous to posting this at somoeone else's suggestion, but could not get accurate results. How do I filter the RANK to get all the appropriate rows for the date? When I still filter on WHERE ROW_NUM = 1, not all of my results show up. Some people may have 1 row of results and others may have more, depending upon how their allocation was split.

Comment: @SeanBarry - I am getting two for Bob and Jane and one for Bruce using Rank = 1.